# Icon in notification center

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

in my app I'm using UILocalNotification. I would like to show notification with icon like in here:[image]

Here is my code responsible for creating local notification:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
notification.fireDate = date;
notification.alertBody = body;
notification.alertTitle = title;
notification.userInfo = userInfo;
notification.category = category;


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

I found "alertLaunchImage" field in "UILocalNotification" object but it seems to not working. Can you please tell me how I can add custom icons to local notification?